# Read and display an element in a html(xml) file by using Xpath in oracle form

Tags: html, xpath, plsql, oracle12c, oracleforms

I want to read "Value new" column changes in my html file and display element value by using `Xpath(4ex:/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[6] )` in Oracle form, may I get suggestions for that?

My output in oracle form should be:

```
0015: IF :NB_CNTRL.FROM_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN
0016: LV_SQL := LV_SQL || ' AND TRUNC(NB_RECEIPT_DATE) >= ''' ||to_char(:NB_CNTRL.FROM_DATE, 'dd-MON-rrrr')||'''';
```

[sample of HTML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsYD2.jpg)

> 

```
<!-- saved from url=(0043)file:///c:/FRM_05.fmb.html -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <!--<base href="\\HTMLPictures\">--><base href=".">
  <style type="text/css">
        body,html,table {font-family: "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;font-size: 12px;line-height: 1.5em;}
  </style>
  <title>Compare</title>

</head>
<body>

<table width="100%" border="0">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th width="30%">Name</th>
    <th width="50px">Changes</th>
    <th width="20px">&nbsp;</th>
    <th width="35%">Value Old</th>
    <th width="20px">&nbsp;</th>
    <th width="35%">Value New</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="lin"><td class="lvl8">(adjoining line)</td><td></td><td class=""></td><td class="">0015:  IF :NB_CNTRL.FROM_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN</td><td class=""></td><td class="">0015:  IF :NB_CNTRL.FROM_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN</td></tr>
<tr class="lin"><td class="lvl8">(line changed)</td><td><img src="./Compare_files/changes_mod.gif"></td><td class="cmpChanged"></td><td class="cmpChanged">0016:    LV_SQL := LV_SQL || ' AND TRUNC(NB_RECEIPT_DATE) &gt;= ''' ||to_char(:NB_CNTRL.FROM_DATE, 'dd-MON-yyyy')||'''';</td><td class="cmpChanged"></td><td class="cmpChanged">0016:    LV_SQL := LV_SQL || ' AND TRUNC(NB_RECEIPT_DATE) &gt;= ''' ||to_char(:NB_CNTRL.FROM_DATE, 'dd-MON-rrrr')||'''';</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Comment: post your xml so we can create an xpath for you

Comment: @shubham: we have XPath, the issue is how to open html file, for instance in c# we have xml reader which u can pass xpath and extract data. Now, siti question is how to parse htnl file, ia there any reader? What is the best practice?

Comment: First of all HTML and XML are both different thing .. yes they both are having dom but they are different.. selenium can read element from html but not from XML ... Now if your source is html , can you tell is it hosted on your localhost like localhost:8080

Comment: @ShubhamJain: please read my question again, i added example. is there any other way except using selenium? do you have any example using selenium in oracle form by java?

Comment: updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExtractValue` should work for you in oracle form

XPath will be like :-

```
/html/body/table//thead/tr[1]/th[6]/text()  -> it will return ->  "0015: IF :NB_CNTRL.FROM_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN"

/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]/text()  -> it will return ->  "0016: LV_SQL := LV_SQL || ' AND TRUNC(NB_RECEIPT_DATE) >= ''' ||to_char(:NB_CNTRL.FROM_DATE, 'dd-MON-rrrr')||''''"
```

I do not have experince in oracle form but It should be like :-

```
ExtractValue(Value(p),'/html/body/table//thead/tr[1]/th[6]/text()') as value
```

OR

```
execute immediate 'alter session set events =''31156 trace name context forever, level 2''';

     l_xml := xmltype(l_clob);

     execute immediate 'alter session set events =''31156 trace name context off''';

     select extractvalue( l_xml
                        , '/html/body/table//thead/tr[1]/th[6]/text()' )
     into l_value
     from dual;

     dbms_output.put_line(l_value);

   end;
```

Source :-

[XML Oracle: Extract specific attribute from multiple repeating child nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34925399/xml-oracle-extract-specific-attribute-from-multiple-repeating-child-nodes)

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2381518

Moreover, You can only test HTML based websites with Selenium. If the Oracle application exposes an HTML based front end that is accessible via a web browser then you can use Selenium to test it, if not you can't.

Please let me know if you can access it using browser, if yes then I will create a script for you in java which will retrieve values for you.